# Pandas: Selecting Multiple Column Values by Adjacent Column Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use the following code snippet to get the adjacent 'Policy Name' column in a data frame when I have the 'Client Name':

```
 policy = df.loc[df['Client Name'] == machine.lower(), 'Policy Name']
```

If there are multiple rows for the 'Client Name' and they have different policies, how can I grab them all? As it stands, the current code gets me the last entry in the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

> As it stands, the current code gets me the last entry in the data
>   frame.

This isn't true. See below for a minimal counter-example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Client Name': ['philip', 'ursula', 'frank', 'ursula'],
                   'Policy Name': ['policy1', 'policy2', 'policy3', 'policy4']})

machine = 'Ursula'

policy = df.loc[df['Client Name'] == machine.lower(), 'Policy Name']

print(policy)

1    policy2
3    policy4
Name: Policy Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: I stringify the object:     policy = policy.to_string(header=None, index=None). Is that leaving me one? Running additional validation now.

Comment: So don't use [`pd.DataFrame.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) or assign it at the end to a different variable, e.g. `policy_string = policy.to_string(...)`. This method is to `Render a DataFrame to a console-friendly tabular output.` It won't help you with slicing or indexing.

Comment: I'm selecting certain values out of the dataframe to go into a CSV, hence the to_string (the additional parameters to get rid of the index & object type).

Comment: @user3425900, You need to supply a [mcve]. I've supplied an example where it works fine. Can you *show* an example [*in your question itself*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51950212/edit) where it doesn't work?

Comment: Your example clearly shows it works. I've run it as well with to_string and it comes across so now I'm trying to identify in my code where the additional value are getting lost. Ty!